# Can't delete failed jobs (laravel 7)

Tags: laravel

I have a couple thousand failed jobs in my redis queue and every time I start up Horizon, they all retry and fail. I need to get rid of them all.

I've tried `php artisan queue:flush` which outputs the message "All failed jobs deleted successfully!"

But they're all still there.

I've noticed on Laravel 8 Horizion documentation, they added `php artisan horizon:clear`, but I can't upgrade right now. What can I do to delete everything?